# libvlc .sdp playback error

Tags: android, libvlc, vlc-android

I want to play video on vlc player on Android.
The options I gave
--aout = opensles
--audio-time-stretch
I gave it to -vvv.

Below is an error.

```
D/VLC: [9c77b030/1bab] core input: `file:///storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp' 

gives access `file' demux `any' path `/storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp'
     D/VLC: [b47fb6d0/1bab] core input source: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp' file='/storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp'
     D/VLC: [b47fb770/1bab] core demux: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 6 candidates
     D/VLC: [b47fb770/1bab] core demux: no access_demux modules matched
     D/VLC: [9c74d270/1bab] core stream: creating access: file:///storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp
     D/VLC: [9c74d270/1bab] core stream:  (path: /storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp)
     D/VLC: [9c74d270/1bab] core stream: looking for access module matching "file": 20 candidates
     D/VLC: [9c74d270/1bab] core stream: using access module "filesystem"
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 25 candidates
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] cache_read stream: Using stream method for AStream*
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] cache_read stream: starting pre-buffering
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] cache_read stream: received first data after 0 ms
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] cache_read stream: pre-buffering done 310 bytes in 0s - 237 KiB/s
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] core stream: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 25 candidates
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] lua stream: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/com.aber.bakon_ffmpeg/app_vlc/.share/lua/playlist
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] lua stream: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/playlist
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] core stream: no stream_filter modules matched
     D/VLC: [9c8d2830/1bab] core stream_directory: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
     D/VLC: [9c8d2830/1bab] core stream_directory: no stream_directory modules matched
     D/VLC: [b47fb6d0/1bab] core input source: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] core stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 25 candidates
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] core stream: using stream_filter module "record"
     D/VLC: [b47fb6d0/1bab] core input source: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp' file='/storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp'
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] core demux: looking for demux module matching "any": 45 candidates
     D/VLC: [a96e17c0/1bab] core xml reader: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
     D/VLC: [a96e17c0/1bab] core xml reader: using xml reader module "xml"
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] mod demux: MOD validation failed (ext=sdp)
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] ts demux: TS module discarded (lost sync)
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] avformat demux: trying url: /storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] avformat demux: CPU flags: 0x0000003f
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] vobsub demux: this doesn't seem to be a vobsub file
     W/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] ps demux: this does not look like an MPEG PS stream, continuing anyway
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] core demux: using demux module "ps"
     D/VLC: [9c77b030/1bab] core input: looking for a subtitle file in /storage/emulated/0/
     D/VLC: [aad61770/1bab] core demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
     D/VLC: [aad61770/1bab] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/com.aber.bakon_ffmpeg/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/reader
     D/VLC: [aad61770/1bab] lua demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/meta/reader
     D/VLC: [aad61770/1bab] core demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
     D/VLC: [9c77b030/1bab] core input: `file:///storage/emulated/0/aber.sdp' successfully opened
     W/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] ps demux: garbage at input from 307, trying to resync...
     D/VLC: [9c77b030/1bab] core input: EOF reached
     D/VLC: [b47fb810/1bab] core demux: removing module "ps"
     D/VLC: [9c74d3f0/1bab] core stream: removing module "record"
     D/VLC: [9c74d330/1bab] core stream: removing module "cache_read"
     D/VLC: [9c74d270/1bab] core stream: removing module "filesystem"
     W/art: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[14,tid=7083,Native,Thread*=0x9c7fa500,peer=0x12e080a0,"VlcObject"]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is no answer I want.
Am I not finding it? T.T.